# Docker Windows Container with Service Fabric on Windows Server

Tags: docker, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I have a Service Fabric cluster installed on 5 virtual machines which are running Windows Server 2016. I would like to run docker windows container inside my Service Fabric cluster. I'm fairly new to the SF and Docker and I have couple of questions:

1. To make it work do I have to install Docker on each node? (If so which version CE or EE?) Because when I deploy my SF app with windows container service inside, it gives me an error during application start `Error event: SourceId='System.Hosting', Property='Download:1.0:1.0:45cc185a-abde-47f4-9a1f-943ad6e29d23'.
   There was an error during download.Container deployment is not supported on the node.`
2. Can I run linux container on Service Fabric installed on Windows Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes you need to have the Containers feature enabled. Or, when running in Azure, you can use a host with the Containers feature already enabled, e.g. '2016-Datacenter-with-Containers'.
2. No, [you can't](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-containers/issues/2) do that inside a cluster at this time.

More info:

- [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-containers-overview)
- [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-containers)